# Meu firefox nao renderediza corretamente minha magina

Tags: html5, css3, firefox, flexbox

Sempre uso o crome pra fazer meus testes nas paginas que estou desenvolvendo lá no crome fica tudo ok... Mas quando vou renderizar a mesma pagina no firefox, as letras ficam levemente achatadas e as medidas e espaçamentos dos elementos ficam diferentes... Desorganizados... Não ao extremo, mas ficam... Por exemplo, no crome, um botão é de um tamanho e se comporta de maneira correta, mas no firefox o mesmo botão fica menor ou maior e ainda se comporta de maneira diferente... As tecnologias que utilizo são apenas HTML5, CSS3 e Flexbox basicamente...

Comment: Cada navegador têm sua forma de interpretar o código, sendo assim, cabe ao desenvolvedor gerir o código de forma eficiente para que o código se adapte a estas diferentes circunstâncias.

Comment: Tendi mano... Só que sou novato, to começando agora e to apanhando pra caramba... Não sei o que seria esse gerir que vc diz no contexto do meu problema... Mas obg pela resposta... hehe

Comment: Cara edita sua resposta é coloca seu código html/css, se possível coloca tbm um print de como esta no Chrome e no firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algo que talvez ajude é um CSS reset

```
html, body, span, p, form, img, a, ul, ol, li, table, tr, td, div{
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
border:none; 
outline:none;
list-style-type:none;
}
```

Nota: esta é uma solução parcial, uma vez que é necessario verificar se cada estilização em css funciona em cada navegador. Também é necessario verificar se os formatos dos arquivos são suportados pelo navegador.

Comment: Infelizmente nao funcionou... =/

Comment: @TonyIvan antes de você começar a codificar você deve colocar este código, não depois de 'pronto'

Comment: eu comecei usando assim...

*{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    list-style-type:none;
}


é quase a mesma coisa não?